# Azure Service Fabric deployment through VSTS - Create-DiffPackage warning

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

How to get rid of the below warning while deploying Azure Service Fabric through VSTS.

The names of some imported commands from the module 'Create-DiffPackage' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.

Comment: What was the output of the Import-Module command with the -Verbose parameter?

Answer (score 1):

It is the task issue, you can follow this issue here: [Service fabric deploy task 'Create-DiffPackage' include unapproved verbs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6778).

On the other hand, this blog is about Approved Verbs that may benefit you: [Why Use Approved Verbs?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timid/2013/07/03/why-use-approved-verbs/)